# What is the solution to Check internet connectivity

Tags: android, android-studio

**getnetworkInfo**' is deprecated , what is the solution? I am using **compilesdkversion** 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `getActiveNetworkInfo()` instead of `getnetworkinfo` , because there were some other factors which weren't considered before ,like network state can vary app to app while using `getnetworkinfo` hence deprecated [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
  // yeah we are online
}else{
  // oops! no network
}
```

Note : put a nullity check too to confirm it is not null before accessing the network  status

Answer (score 1):

Simple way !

```
  public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET || info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How to use just check

```
if (!isConnectingToInternet(getContext())) {
   // here no internet connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class NetworkUtils {

        public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return (activeNetwork != null)
                    && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }

}
```

Use this class to **check network connection as**:

```
if(NetworkUtils.isConnected(getContext())) {
     //Call your network related task                      
  } else {
     //Show a toast displaying no network connection
    }
```

Comment: why downvote??care to explain??

Comment: this solution is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConnectivityManager` to get network access. you can use `BroadcastReceiver` to get constant updates of your network status.

```
package your_package_name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectivityStatus extends ContextWrapper{
public ConnectivityStatus(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public static boolean isConnected(Context context){

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo connection = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (connection != null && connection.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

Receive updates from your network class, use this in your main class where to update status.
Register `Receiver` on class
`getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));`

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!ConnectivityStatus.isConnected(getContext())){
            //not connected
        }else {
            //connected
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Really very helpful for me , thanks

Comment: @user2990506 Accept my answer man, Its unique here.